# Add coordinates to an existing gpplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some centroid positions which I would like to add to my existing ggplot but I am not sure how I could go about doing this. I have tried creating two ggplots and tried combining them but this did not seem to work out since my centroids do not have an `E` value which resulted in `Error in factor(E) : object 'E' not found`

My goal is to have the data and the centroids appear all inside plot1 so we can see the data and the centroid positions.

Data for plot1 [Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1s732frr62wk7h/data.csv?dl=0)

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")

data2 <- data[, -c(1)]

data2$E <- ifelse(is.na(data2$E1), data2$E2, data2$E1)

library(ggplot2)

x <- c(2,6.2, 8.8)
y <- c(3.5, 8.8, 2.4)
# Format centroid positions to be a 2D point with coordinates
coords = paste(x,y, sep=",")
df = data.frame(x,y)

plot1 <- ggplot(data2, aes(X, Y, shape = factor(E))) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8, 3), name = "E") +
  theme_bw()
  
plot2 <- plot1 + 
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x,y), col="blue") +
  geom_label(aes(x+.5,y+0.5,label=coords))
```

Data

```
structure(list(Subject = 1:15, X = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), Y = c(1L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 
10L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 5L), E1 = c(1L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), E2 = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: It'd be great if you can copy and paste your data here instead of using an external link (you can use the function `dput(data)`. Most of the people will not download unknown file from unknown source :)

Comment: @benson23 Updated the post with data from dput. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you want to work with two different dataframes with different lengths in a ggplot. So this means that you have to set the `ggplot()` empty and use the two dataframes in the `geom_point` commands with `mapping =`  for the aesthetics.You can use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data2$E <- as.factor(ifelse(is.na(data2$E1), data2$E2, data2$E1))

# Remove one NA in column E
data2 <- data2[!is.na(data2$E),]

x <- c(2,6.2, 8.8)
y <- c(3.5, 8.8, 2.4)
# Format centroid positions to be a 2D point with coordinates
coords = paste(x,y, sep=",")
df = data.frame(x,y)

plot1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data2, mapping = aes(X, Y, shape = E), size = 4) +
  geom_point(df, mapping=aes(x = x, y = y,), col="blue") +
  geom_label(aes(x+.5,y+0.5,label=coords)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8, 3), name = "E") +
  theme_bw()

plot1
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The main problem (and the reason for `Error in factor(E) : object 'E' not found` is that the the criteria provided to your `ggplot()` call get inherited to your later `geom_point()` and `geom_label()`. But since you there provide a new `data =`, it cannot find the inherited `E`.
So you can do as suggested by @Quinten or add `inherit.aes = FALSE`, as in my solution.

**Data**

```
structure(list(Subject = 1:15, X = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), Y = c(1L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 
10L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 5L), E1 = c(1L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), E2 = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

data2 <- data %>% filter(!if_all(c(E1, E2), is.na)) %>% mutate(E = ifelse(is.na(E1), E2, E1))
x <- c(2,6.2, 8.8)
y <- c(3.5, 8.8, 2.4)
coords = paste(x , y, sep = ",")
df = data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(data2, aes(X, Y, shape = factor(E))) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8, 3), name = "E") +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x, y), col = "blue", size = 3, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_label(df, mapping = aes(x + .5, y + 0.5, label = coords), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

**Output**

[image]